# Pygame how to detect clicks from a list of images

Tags: python, pygame

For my levels screen I use images for each level button, there are 15 on a page. I was able to blit them all to the screen in a nice layout using some iteration and math, I have been trying to figure out a way to do this with the **click detection** aswell. But I do not want to type "var = get_rect" 15 times a page.

All of the images are in a list for iteration,

```
self.levels_p1 = [self.l1, self.l2, self.l3, self.l4, self.l5,
                     self.l6, self.l7, self.l8, self.l9, self.l10,
                     self.l11, self.l12, self.l13, self.l14, self.l15,]
```

and are added to the screen in a 5 x 3 like this,

```
            for i, lvl in enumerate(self.levels_p1, start=1):
                x = ((WIDTH - 100) * (i % 5) // 6) + 17
                y = HEIGHT // 10 + ((i // 5) * 125)
                if i % 5 == 0:
                    x = ((WIDTH - 100) * 5 // 6) + 17
                    y = HEIGHT // 10 + (((i // 5) - 1) * 125)
                self.screen.blit(lvl, (x, y))
                if self.level_unlocked < i:
                    self.screen.blit(self.level_shade, (x, y))
```

And I have been detecting clicks like this,

```
            mousepos = pg.mouse.get_pos()

            for event in pg.event.get():
                if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                    pg.quit()
                if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    #to menu
                    if self.back_rect.collidepoint(*mousepos):
                        on_levels = False
                        self.swipe.play()
                        self.start()
                    #to levels2 page
                    if self.arrow_rect.collidepoint(*mousepos):
                        on_levels = False
                        self.swipe.play()
                        self.levels_page2()
                    #to level 1
                    if self.l1_rect.collidepoint(*mousepos):
                        on_levels = False
                        self.swipe.play()
                        self.load_level(1)
```

But that will only work for all the levels if I manually define a rect for all of the buttons, which is what I am trying to avoid.

I was wondering if there is a good way to detect the **clicks** on each and every one of these buttons? Similarly to how I displayed them in the 2nd code bit.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Improvement: `self.levels_p1 = [getattr(self, f"l{¡}") for i in range(1, 16)]`

Comment: `for i, val in enumerate(lvls):
    if lvls[i].collidepoint(*mousepos):
        on_levels = False
        self.swipe.play()
        self.load_level(i+1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.Surface.blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) returns a rectangle with the area of the affected pixels:

```py
self.rect = self.screen.blit(self.level_shade, (x, y))
```

Alternatively you can get the bounding rectangle of a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) by [`get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect). The location of this rectangle is (0, 0). Hence, you have to set the position by a keyword argument:

```py
self.rect = self.level_shade.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))
```

Comment: I tend to overlook the simple answers, this was pretty much the solution. I got this to work by defining an empty list before the loop, and appending all the level button's rect to the list, then checking the indexes of the list when testing for the clicks.

Answer (score 1):

```
if self.arrow_rect.collidepoint(*mousepos)
```

I don't know what you're packing on the line above.  If you want to detect clicks,  I think you should get mouse position first. I'll do something like this:

```
for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                pg.quit()
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                #to menu
                mousepos = pg.mouse.get_pos() #Here lies the magic and no need to unpack
                if self.back_rect.collidepoint(mousepos):
                    on_levels = False
                    self.swipe.play()
                    self.start()
                #to levels2 page
                if self.arrow_rect.collidepoint(mousepos):
                    on_levels = False
                    self.swipe.play()
                    self.levels_page2()
                #to level 1
                if self.l1_rect.collidepoint(mousepos):
                    on_levels = False
                    self.swipe.play()
                    self.load_level(1)
```

If that solves your problem please let me know and of it doesn't still let me know!

**Edit:** Try if/elif block instead of just if.

Comment: theres other stuff, i can get mouse positions, and i do get it earlier in the loop. I'm trying to detect collision between a point and a rectangle that does not exist. I provided the code for how the 15 levels are displayed in a grid from a list, using math and iteration. Can the same be done for the click detection without going l1 = get_rect l2 = get_rect, and so on all the way down?

Comment: i did notice copying messed up all of my indentation in the code provided, this is fixed now. The grid loop should be more understandable now

Answer (score 1):

```
        mousepos = pg.mouse.get_pos()
        lvls = []

        for i, lvl in enumerate(self.levels_p1):
            #x, y topleft for 5x3 grid with easement and centered
            x = ((WIDTH - 100) * (i % 5) // 5) + 110
            y = HEIGHT // 10 + ((i // 5) * 125)
            #add to screen
            temp = self.screen.blit(lvl, (x, y))
            #if not unlocked
            if self.level_unlocked < i:
                #darken
                self.screen.blit(self.level_shade, (x, y))
            #if unlocked
            else:
                #enlarged version if hovering over and unlocked
                if temp.collidepoint(*mousepos):
                    self.screen.blit(self.levels_1l[i], (x-6, y-6))
                #rect list for click detection
                lvls.append(temp)

        #back button interactive
        if self.back_rect.collidepoint(*mousepos):
            self.screen.blit(self.t_back2, self.back_rect2)  # bigger
        else:
            self.screen.blit(self.t_back, self.back_rect)  # normal
        #arrow button interactive
        if self.arrow_rect.collidepoint(*mousepos):
            self.screen.blit(self.arrowr2, self.arrow_rect2)  # bigger
        else:
            self.screen.blit(self.arrowr, self.arrow_rect)  # normal

        pg.display.flip()
        #all button presses
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                pg.quit()
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                #to menu
                if self.back_rect.collidepoint(*mousepos):
                    on_levels = False
                    self.swipe.play()
                    self.start()
                #to levels2 page
                if self.arrow_rect.collidepoint(*mousepos):
                    on_levels = False
                    self.swipe.play()
                    self.levels_page2()
                #to level
                for i, val in enumerate(lvls):
                    #if clicked pos = level pos
                    if lvls[i].collidepoint(*mousepos):
                        on_levels = False
                        self.swipe.play()
                        #level to load
                        self.load_level(i+1)
```